# How can I parse this JSON output for the SMMRY API?

Tags: java, json, android-volley, smmry

```
{  
     "sm_api_character_count": "1284",
     "sm_api_content_reduced": "64%",
     "sm_api_title": "‘Schoolhouse Rock\\'",
     "sm_api_content": " Musician Bob Dorough, 94, best known as a 
     composer 
     and performer for ABC's educational series of short cartoons 
     Schoolhouse Rock!, died of natural causes at his Mount Bethel, 
     Pa., home on Monday, his son, Chris, said. Mc Call asked Mr. 
     Dorough to put the multiplication tables to music, leading to 
     \"Three Is a Magic Number,\" as well as a Multiplication Rock 
     collection.",
     "sm_api_limitation": "Waited 0 extra seconds due to API Free mode, 
     97 requests left to make for today."
}
```

[image: Image of JSON Output now visible]

I'm using an API called smmry and I'm trying to parse the "sm_api_content" JSON object to get the summary of a linked article. However, I'm having difficulty doing so. According to smmry, these objects are wrapped in a JSON array, but I don't know what this array is called (as there are no square brackets in the screenshot to indicate an array).

```
try {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                "https://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY="
                        + API_KEY + "&SM_URL=" + "https://www.studentnewsdaily.com/daily-news-article/schoolhouse-rock/",
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(final JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString(2));
                        } catch (JSONException ignored) { }
                        try {
                            String theSummary = response
                                    .getJSONObject("sm_api_content")
                                    .toString();
                            TextView getSummary = findViewById(R.id.getSummary);
                            getSummary.setText(theSummary);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(final VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is what I'm currently doing, but obviously it isn't working. Any guidance or help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could you plz paste the json or link where one can see the json structure

Comment: If you click the link at the top of the post it should take you to a screenshot of the JSON output

Comment: Can you please add it as formatted JSON text, not an image?

Comment: From the screenshot, `'sm_api_content'` is just a string node in the json. So instead of `response.getJSONObject("sm_api_content")` use `response.get("sm_api_content")` or `response.getString("sm_api_content")`. Exact method I can't tell as I am unaware of the lib you are using

Comment: I've added the output as a formatted JSON text. Unfortunately, I tried .getString("sm_api_content) and it also did not work (using get will return an object for me).

Comment: 1. Json you pasted is invalid, use https://jsoneditoronline.org/ to format and validate. 2. What is the output of response.toString(2), is it the same json you pasted

Comment: There is no output upon clicking the button in my app (after doing response.get("sm_api_content").toString(); or response.getString("sm_api_content"). No errors either, just nothing happens

Comment: @TimKrash, try to Log/ Toast the "theSummary" variable in your code, to check whether you are getting the content in response.